# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? on ubuntu

Tags: docker

I'm trying to change my docker network to docker 0 (10.10.10.10/24 series) on ubuntu. I created docker.conf file in path /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d and my docker version is 18.09.0.

Following is the docker.conf file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
BindsTo=containerd.service
After=network-online.target firewalld.service
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues stil                                                                                        l
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --bip=10.10.10.10/24
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
LimitNOFILE=1048576
# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
# Uncomment TasksMax if your systemd version supports it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this version.
TasksMax=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containe                                                                                        rs
Delegate=yes
# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process
# restart the docker process if it exits prematurely
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitInterval=60s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that I followed [this link](https://container-solutions.com/set-the-ip-of-the-docker-bridge-with-systemd/)

Could anybody suggest how to change my default network to docker 0?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you do not have Docker Desktop installed and running, which enables the docker daemon.
Run sudo dockerd to start the docker daemon service.

Answer (score 0):

In most platforms, there's a docker user group that's added, but it depends on the installer as to whether or not you're added to it. I'd add yourself `usermod -aG docker <user>` After that, log out and back in and see if you can access it.

The Docker socket, /var/run/docker.sock is a network socket accessed as a file, meaning it has file permissions, and in most cases it is owned by root, in the docker group, allowing the docker group to access and use it.